# PHP intersect multidimensional indexed associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have two multidimensional arrays, first is index, and its sub arrays are associative arrays.

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 6
    )

)
```

and

```
  Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
         [layout_id] => 1
         [element_id] => 1
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 8
    )

)
```

**EDIT** 
Expected result should be

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Array
      (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 5
    )
)
```

The length of both the arrays could be different.
I want Duplicate entries from these both arrays. is there in built function in php to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show expected output, plus any attempts you have made that did not work

Comment: Use array_intersect_assoc() function of php

Comment: array_intersect_assoc returns first index of first array, [0] => Array
    (
        [layout_id] => 1
        [element_id] => 1
    )

Comment: use array_map or array_walk with array_intersect_assoc. Google it you will come to know

Answer (score 0):

Use array_uintersect() to use a custom comparison function, like this:

```
$arr1 = array(
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 2),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 4),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 5),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 6),
);

$arr2 = array(
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 1),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 2),
    array('layout_id' => 1, 'element_id' => 5),
);

$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'customCompare');

function customCompare($val1, $val2) {
    if ($val1['layout_id'] == $val2['layout_id'] && $val1['element_id'] == $val2['element_id']) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return *any number, exept 0*;
    }
}
```

if customCompare return 0 it means $val1 and $val2 are equal.

Comment: this returns first array as it is.